# Products from SQL database not showing in Shopware 5 products overview

Tags: php, shopware

When I go to my phpMyAdmin DB, the products i imported are showing, but they are not showing in my Shopware admin panel. Any idea what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly the case, when you missed to create the corresponding attributes in the s_articles_attributes table.

```
INSERT INTO `s_articles_attributes` (`articleID`, `articledetailsID`)
SELECT d.articleID, d.id
FROM `s_articles_details` d
LEFT JOIN `s_articles_attributes` at
ON at.articledetailsID = d.id
WHERE at.id IS NULL;
```